# Krusader/dolphin safe to use for sftp without sha256?

Tags: kde, sftp, krusader, sha256

I always use **Krusader** for (s)ftp. The dual pane is a sheer delight, better feel then Nautulis/Files. Version 2.4.0-beta3 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Recently I got error messages connecting on some updated servers (sftp://user@xxxx):

```
no match for method mac algo client->server
```

The client supports only hmac-ssha1, and the server has this disabled for security reasons.

AFAIK Krusader uses KIO (like Dolphin) and there is a [bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344517) and there will be support in the next updated libssh 0.7.0 library. Actually just [released](https://www.libssh.org/2015/05/11/libssh-0-7-0/).

How can I connect? Is hmac-sha1 really unsafe or can I enable it on the server? How do I fix my Krusader? Can I recompile it with libssh-0-7-0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fish:// protocol instead of sftp://

Krusader doesn't do:

```
sftp://user@xxxxx/
```

it gives the error message.

But is **does** do:

```
fish://user@xxxxx/
```

I dunno what the fish:// protocol is, but it is good catch.

Comment: `fish://` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files_transferred_over_shell_protocol  Good catch indeed. I remember using it a decade ago. At some time I switched to `sftp://` until it failed me today. Back to fish then. Even Debian Sid doesn't use libssh0.7 yet.